# Context Provider Response is not recognized

Tags: fiware-orion

Using the latest development version:

I have registered a context provider for an attribute. When the attribute is asked the context provider is interrogated through a POST request which returns

```
curl -v --request POST http://130.206.83.68/ngsi10/queryContext
* About to connect() to 130.206.83.68 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 130.206.83.68... connected
> POST /ngsi10/queryContext HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1     zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: 130.206.83.68
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 206
< Date: Fri, 27 Mar 2015 11:09:05 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host 130.206.83.68 left intact
* Closing connection #0
{"contextResponses":[{"contextElement": 
{"isPattern":false,"id":"Madrid","type":"Ciudad",
"attributes":[{"name":"population7","value":"6000","type":"string"}]},
"statusCode": {"code":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK"}}]}
```

However Orion does not recognize the response and the following trace appears:

INFO@10:59:36  clientSocketHttp.cpp[154]: Starting transaction to  130.206.83.68:80/ngsi10/queryContext

INFO@10:59:36  clientSocketHttp.cpp[364]: Notification Successfully Sent to 130.206.83.68:80/ngsi10/queryContext

INFO@10:59:36  clientSocketHttp.cpp[375]: Transaction ended
WARNING@10:59:36  postQueryContext.cpp[211]: Other Error (context provider response to QueryContext is empty)

INFO@10:59:36  rest.cpp[383]: Transaction ended

Comment: just to note that orion issues the request with  {"user-agent":"orion/0.19.0-next libcurl/7.22.0","host":"130.206.83.68:80","accept":"application/xml, application/json","content-length":"241","content-type":"application/xml"}

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably due to current Orion version (0.19.0) assumes always that the context providers implement XML rendering. Thus, if your context provider responses in JSON, Orion will not understand the response.

The solution is to implement XML in your context provider (or wait until Orion implement [the proper mechanism](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/722)).